# Getting the following error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement command-not-found==0.3

Tags: django, heroku

I am deploying a Django app using Heroku.

When I run

```
git push heroku master
```

in my terminal I get the following error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement command-not-found==0.3"

When I run

```
sudo apt-get install command-not-found
```

I find that command-not-found is version 20.04.2. However, `pip freeze` tells me `command-not-found` is version 0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command-not-found` [doesn't seem to exist on PyPI](https://pypi.org/search/?q=command-not-found), but it [is a package in Ubuntu](https://packages.debian.org/buster/command-not-found) and [Debian repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/command-not-found). It doesn't look like anything that your application should depend on, and it certainly doesn't belong on Heroku.

I suspect

- you're trying to create your dependencies file after the fact, by simply doing `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, and
- that you're either not working in a virtual environment or you created your virtual environment with system packages.

This is an antipattern that will cause several packages that your application doesn't actually need to be included in your `requirements.txt`. In this case it is even including Python packages that come from system packages and aren't meant to be installed from PyPI. Your `requirements.txt` should contain *only* your *actual* dependencies.

Instead of creating it with `pip freeze` after the fact, add things to that file *before*, and install them into your virtual environment with the same `pip install -r requirements.txt` command that you'll use in production. I also *very strongly* urge you to use a virtual environment.

In this case, I suggest you edit your `requirements.txt` and remove anything you don't actually need, commit, and redeploy.